# Ember Dynamic Input Value from Model - HTMLbars

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

Assuming the following model:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return ['car', 'truck', 'boat'];
  }
});
```

I can loop through the model like so:

```
{{#each model as |vehicle index|}}
    {{vehicle}} - #{{index}}
{{/each}}
```

which would result in this:

```
car - #0
truck - #1
boat - #2
```

However, what if I wanted dynamic properties in an input (I know the following does not work the way I want):

```
{{#each model as |vehicle index|}}
    {{input value=vehicle}}
{{/each}}
```

Which results in all of the input fields loading with the value already defined:  car, truck, and boat in the input.

What I want to make happen is this (assuming you looped through the model, it would 'output' this):

```
{{input value=car}}
{{input value=truck}}
{{input value=boat}}
```

but it's not outputting that, it outputs this:

```
{{input value="car"}}
{{input value="truck"}}
{{input value="boat"}}
```

The values are already defined but I would like to define **'car'** in the model (meaning it has no value) I'm only setting up the name of the input and then later, I would be able to access **{{car}}** so that whatever the user types in the blank input, it outputs to **{{car}}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over the Ember docs, they show an example of [Binding dynamic attribute](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_binding-dynamic-attribute) to an input helper

To refer back to the above example the final code would be:

```
{{#each model as |vehicle index|}}
    {{input value=(mut (get this vehicle))}}
{{/each}}
```

And if you reference **{{car}}** in your document, as you type in the input... it would display.